# Check if a list contains two elements of different derived types

Tags: c#, linq

I want to check a list of elements to see if it contains at least two elements of a particular derived type.  Currently my implementation looks like this:

```
    public override bool IsEnabledForTechnology(List<TechnologyBase> enabledTechnologies)
    {
        return enabledTechnologies.Any(t => t.GetType() == typeof(TechnologyA)) && enabledTechnologies.Any(t => t.GetType() == typeof(TechnologyB));
    }
```

What is the most effective statement to acheive this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `OfType` to filter the list by type:

```
public override bool IsEnabledForTechnology(List<TechnologyBase> enabledTechnologies)
{
    return enabledTechnologies.OfType<TechnologyA>.Any() && 
           enabledTechnologies.OfType<TechnologyB>.Any();
}
```

Comment: Isn't this less efficient because "OfType<>" will iterate the entire list whereas .Any(...) will return a bool as soon as a matching condition is found?

Comment: I believe that this will be lazily evaluated, so that `OfType` itself won't iterate, but only as necessary to fulfill the `Any`. 

From MSDN: This method is implemented by using deferred execution. The immediate return value is an object that stores all the information that is required to perform the action. The query represented by this method is not executed until the object is enumerated either by calling its GetEnumerator method directly or by using foreach in Visual C# or For Each in Visual Basic.

Answer (score 0):

```
return enabledTechnologies.Any( t => { return (t.GetType() == typeof(TechnologyA)) && (t.GetType() == typeof(TechnologyB));} )
```

This removes at least one foreach cycle. Also can replace `t.GetType()` with temporary variable in lambda, but optimizer should do it for you.